# Run function inside function php

Tags: php, mysql

Happy new year!:)

I'm fairly new to PHP and i'm trying to write a function to get the childs of the parent categories, and re use that function again to get the childs of childs categories.

However, it is not working as I was hoping, and I can't really figure out why. I hope you have a minute to help me out here.

Thank you! Roy

```
$Parents =

Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [category_id] => 3
        [parent_id] => 1
        [name] => PC Onderdelen
        [is_active] => 1
        [position] => 2
        [level] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [category_id] => 11
        [parent_id] => 1
        [name] => test
        [is_active] => 1
        [position] => 3
        [level] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [category_id] => 14
        [parent_id] => 1
        [name] => Rootcat3
        [is_active] => 1
        [position] => 4
        [level] => 1
    )
)
```

The function

```
public function getchilds($parents)
{
    $subcategories = array();

    foreach ($parents as $parent)
        {
            $parentid = $parent['category_id'];

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_id = $parentid";

            $db = new DB ('novacpos');
            $result = $db->query($sql);

            while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                    $subcategories[] = $rows;
                }
            $parent["children"] = $subcategories;
            unset ($subcategories);
            $parents1[] = $parent;
        }
    return $parents1;
}
```

The result

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [category_id] => 3
        [parent_id] => 1
        [name] => PC Onderdelen
        [is_active] => 1
        [position] => 2
        [level] => 1
        [children] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [category_id] => 4
                        [parent_id] => 3
                        [name] => Moederborden
                        [is_active] => 1
                        [position] => 2
                        [level] => 2
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [category_id] => 6
                        [parent_id] => 3
                        [name] => Behuizingen
                        [is_active] => 1
                        [position] => 1
                        [level] => 2
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [category_id] => 8
                        [parent_id] => 3
                        [name] => Laptops
                        [is_active] => 1
                        [position] => 3
                        [level] => 2
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [category_id] => 9
                        [parent_id] => 3
                        [name] => Muizen
                        [is_active] => 1
                        [position] => 4
                        [level] => 2
                    )

            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [category_id] => 11
        [parent_id] => 1
        [name] => test
        [is_active] => 1
        [position] => 3
        [level] => 1
        [children] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [category_id] => 13
                        [parent_id] => 11
                        [name] => Test2
                        [is_active] => 1
                        [position] => 1
                        [level] => 2
                    )

            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [category_id] => 14
        [parent_id] => 1
        [name] => Rootcat3
        [is_active] => 1
        [position] => 4
        [level] => 1
        [children] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [category_id] => 15
                        [parent_id] => 14
                        [name] => Extracat1
                        [is_active] => 1
                        [position] => 1
                        [level] => 2
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

Result of `print_r ($parent["children"]);`

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [category_id] => 4
        [parent_id] => 3
        [name] => Moederborden
        [is_active] => 1
        [position] => 2
        [level] => 2
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [category_id] => 6
        [parent_id] => 3
        [name] => Behuizingen
        [is_active] => 1
        [position] => 1
        [level] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [category_id] => 8
        [parent_id] => 3
        [name] => Laptops
        [is_active] => 1
        [position] => 3
        [level] => 2
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [category_id] => 9
        [parent_id] => 3
        [name] => Muizen
        [is_active] => 1
        [position] => 4
        [level] => 2
    )

)
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [category_id] => 13
        [parent_id] => 11
        [name] => Test2
        [is_active] => 1
        [position] => 1
        [level] => 2
    )

)
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [category_id] => 15
        [parent_id] => 14
        [name] => Extracat1
        [is_active] => 1
        [position] => 1
        [level] => 2
    )

)
```

So I thought: (but not working)

```
public function getchilds($parents)
{
    $subcategories = array();

    foreach ($parents as $parent)
        {
            $parentid = $parent['category_id'];

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_id = $parentid";

            $db = new DB ('novacpos');
            $result = $db->query($sql);

            while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                    $subcategories[] = $rows;
                }
            $parent["children"] = $subcategories;
            unset ($subcategories);

            getchilds($parent["children"]); <-----------

            $parents1[] = $parent;
        }

    return $parents1;
}
```

Comment: You're calling `getchilds()`, but not doing anything with the result it returns.

Comment: Also, if this is in a class, you should be calling `self::getchilds()`.

Comment: I moved it to a the row below "$parents1[] = $parent;", so inside the function its declared what it should do, right?

Comment: You still need to do something with the value it returns, e.g. `$children = self::getchilds($parent['children'])`

Comment: You should not do SQL queries in loops or nested function calls, that has really bad performance. There are already SQL solutions out there for handling nested sets, so do some research on that.

Answer (score 0):

```
class myModel{
public function get_categories(){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM categories";

            $db = new DB ('novacpos'); // You should use a singleton pattern for this
            $result = $db->query($sql);
            $categories = array();

            while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                    $categories[] = $rows;
                }

     return $categories;
}

public function organize_categories($categories) {
        $resultParents = array();
        $resultChildren = array();

        foreach ($categories as $row) {
            if(empty($row['parent']))
                $resultParents[] = $row;
            else
                $resultChildren[] = $row;
        }

        foreach ($resultParents as &$parent){
            $parent['children'] = $this->_organize_category($resultChildren, $parent['category_id']);
        }
        unset($parent);
        return $resultParents;
    }

    private function _organize_category($resultChildren, $parent) {
        $children = array();
        foreach ($resultChildren as $child) {
            if ($child['parent_id'] == $parent){
                $child['children'] = $this->_organize_category($resultChildren, $child['category_id']);
                $children[] = $child;
            }
        }

        return $children;
    }
}
```

Finally :

```
$categories = $myModel->get_categories();
$organized_categories = $myModel->organize_categories($categories);
var_dump($organized_categories);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's implemented in procedural style, but it works, just rewrite it as you need

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'mysql', 'test');

$parents = [];
$result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM categories WHERE category_id IN (0,1)');

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $parents[] = $row;
}


function getchilds($parents, $db)
{
    foreach ($parents as &$parent)
    {
        $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_id = {$parent['category_id']}");

        if ($result && $result->num_rows > 0)
        {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $parent['children'][] = $row;
            }

            $parent['children'] = getchilds($parent['children'], $db);
        }
    }

    return $parents;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r(getchilds($parents, $db));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I changed my code to this: (your code didnt work straight away)

Comment: public function getchilds($parents)
 {
  $subcategories = array();
  
  foreach ($parents as $parent)
   {
    $parentid = $parent['category_id'];
     
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_id = $parentid";
      
    $db = new DB ('novacpos');
    $result = $db->query($sql);
      
    while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
     {
      $parent["children"][] = $rows;
     }
    $parents[] = $parent;
    $parent["children"] = self::getchilds($parent["children"]);
    
   }
  return $parents;
 }

Comment: See here the result: view-source:http://pos.admin-x.com/pages/productgroups/classtest.php.